# Pictures in HTML files in iOS app

Tags: html, ios, xcode

I'm very new to iOS development and I'm having an issue with displaying an image inside HTML file. I successfully display the html file in a webView but not the images inside it. I have added the png files to the same folder that I retrieve the html file but neither the

`background-image: url(bg1.png);`

nor the

`<img src="logo.png"/>`

seem to work.

I think I've worked out the way to add the external files to iOS app because I successfully set those pictures as the background for webView, my issue is the HTML file does not display it. I also tested the file in several browsers and there's no problem.

Am I writing the paths wrong or is this an even simpler rookie mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using relative paths or file: paths to refer to images does not work with UIWebView. Instead you have to load the HTML into the view with the correct baseURL:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```

You can then refer to your images like this:

```
<img src="myimage.png">
```

Or from within CSS like this:

```
background-image: url(loading.gif)
```

### Example :

```
NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bgfull.png"];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO];
NSString *size = [@"100%25" stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *contentHtml = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html>\
                                 <head>\
                                 <style type=\"text/css\">\
                                 html {height:%@;}\
                                 body {height:%@; margin:0; padding:0; color:white; font-size:40px;}\
                                 #bg {position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:%@; height:%@;}\
                                 #content {position:relative; z-index:1;}\
                                 </style>\
                                 </head>\
                                 <body>\
                                 <div id=\"bg\"><img src=\"%@\" width=\"%@\" height=\"%@\"></div>\
                                 <div id=\"content\"><font color=\"#DAF899\" size=\"+4\"><b>%@</b></font><p>%@</p></div>\
                                 </body>\
                                 </html>", size, size, size, size, url, size, size, self.navigationItem.title, content];

[webView loadHTMLString:contentHtml baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: Is this the only way? My html file isn't exactly short.

Comment: I am not sure but may be its the only way.

Comment: Ok the example actually scared me but the strings at first lines worked like a charm :) thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

Just set the path of your image file in img src tag correctly. You'll get it.  And set width and height of image. And add image file in your project. And for specific answer u can share the details.

**UPDATED:**

```
NSString *readmePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"demo.html" ofType:nil];
    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:readmePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
        NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
        [webview loadHTMLString:html baseURL:baseURL];
```

And demo.html is your html file in your project.
This will resolve your problem and in img src tag just use image file name with extension.

Comment: The images and the html file are in the same folder. Don't know how I wrote the paths wrong there, they are in bunde resources as well : /

Answer (score 1):

I would use `UIImage` or `UIImageView` instead of `UIWebView`. If you are using `UIWebView` amd picture is in the bundle package, you have to declare it with `path` not as `url`. Also you can use `UIWebView` to display image from online source.